# Match two files and retain duplicates

Tags: awk, grep

file 1

```
pears
oranges
apples
pear
pears
pears
apples
apples
grapes
grapes
straw
```

file 2

```
apples
pear
grapes
straw
```

What I need to compare file 1 to 2 and get matches. If it is a duplicate, include that as well.

What I tried

```
grep -f file 1 file 2
```

Which gives me

```
apples
pear
grapes
straw
```

But what I would like is to include the duplicates mapping to file 2 as well

```
 apples
 apples 
 apples
 pear
 grapes
 grapes
 straw
```

Comment: Make sure to include partial matches in both files your example so we can see how they should be handled, e.g. pineapple vs apple and grapefruit vs grape.

Comment: @ed, there are "pear" and "pears" already.

Comment: @glennjackman Ah, thanks, I missed that. Now we just need something similar in the opposite direction to wrap it up, e.g. add apple to file1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=(a[$0]?a[$0] ORS:"")$0;next} ($0 in a){print a[$0]}' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                                ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  a[$0]=(a[$0]?a[$0] ORS:"")$0          ##Creating an array named a whose index is $0 and its keep concatenating its own values with new line and current line value.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                       ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
($0 in a){                              ##Checking condition if $0 is present in array a then do following.
  print a[$0]                           ##Printing array a value whose index is $0.
}
' Input_file1  Input_file2              ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
apples
apples
apples
pear
grapes
grapes
straw
```

Answer (score 2):

You're matching fixed strings, and you want to match the whole line, so add the `-F` and `-x` options to grep.

All you need to do is set file2 as the pattern file:

```
grep -Fxf file2 file1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change the file order in grep, it will give you the desired records but in the original order, also add the right options.

```
$ grep -xFf file2 file1

apples
pear
apples
apples
grapes
grapes
straw
```

However, if you want them in file2 order, `awk` is a better solution.

Here is one solution without `awk`

```
$ join -2 2 <(sort file1) <(nl file2 | sort -k2) | sort -k2n | cut -d' ' -f1

apples
apples
apples
pear
grapes
grapes
straw
```